# 3d Plot of (x,y,z) that looks like histogram3d

Tags: plotting

I'd like to create a 3d "bar plot" of data with three coordinates (xn,yn,zn). The `Histogram3d` function in Mathematica 11 looks great, but I just want to plot triplets, I don't want to count the number of ocurrances of anything. Is there some way to plot various heights associated with points in the (x,y) plane using this nice graphical style?

```
[(x1,y1,z1),
(x2,y2,z2),
...
(xn,yn,zn)]
```

[image]

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127054/22013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is regularly spaced you can use [`WeightedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) with [`Histogram3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html).  If not you could create your own plot with [`Cuboid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cuboid.html) and [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html).

First I'll create some regularly spaced *triplet* $\{x,y,z\}$ data in `dat`.

```
SeedRandom[12345];
With[{hl = HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}]]},
 dat = MapThread[Append, 
    {Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ hl[[1, All, 2 ;;]]], 1], 
     Flatten@hl[[2]]}];
 ]
dat // Short
```

> ```
> {{-3,-(5/2),0},{-3,-2,0},{-3,-(3/2),0},{-3,-1,0},{-3,-(1/2),0},{-3,0,1},
>  <<156>>,
>  {7/2,1/2,1},{7/2,1,0},{7/2,3/2,0},{7/2,2,0},{7/2,5/2,0},{7/2,3,0}}
> ```

## Regularly Spaced Data

With `WeightedData` each $\{x,y\}$ can be given a weight of $z$.  `Histogram3D` understands this information. All that is needed is to specify bins that match the spacing of the data.  In `dat` both $x$ and $y$ are spaced by $\frac{1}{2}$.

```
wdat = WeightedData[dat[[All, ;; -2]], dat[[All, -1]]];
Histogram3D[wdat, {{1/2}, {1/2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## *Triplets* in General

For triplets in general you can create your own histogram-like plot using `Cuboid` and `Graphics3D`.  Here a cuboid is created for each set by taking $\{x,y,0\}$ as the lower corner and  $\{x+\Delta,y+\Delta,z\}$ as the upper corner.  Deltas, colour, lighting, and the rest I leave to you.

```
Graphics3D[{Orange, Cuboid[{#1, #2, 0}, {#1 + .2, #2 + .2, #3}] & @@@ dat}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.