# ListPlot3D Not Showing Last Elements in The List

Tags: plotting

I was using ListPlot3D and noticed that it wasn't plotting the last elements of my two dimensional list. (i.e. My 5x10 matrix was only showing a 4x9 set of data). However, when I use just an arrayplot it works beautifully. A Simple set of data I used is below:

```
    Temp = Table[0, {10}, {5}];
    Temp[[1, 3]] = 10;
    Temp[[2, 2 ;; 4]] = 10;
    Temp[[3 ;; 8, All]] = 10;
    Temp[[9, 2 ;; 4]] = 10;
    Temp[[10, 3]] = 10;

    ArrayPlot[Temp]
```

[image: Sample Array Plot]

```
    ListPlot3D[Temp, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: 3D Image]

When I use the 3D plot, only one point on the diamond show up and the far right side is missing. I specifically want InterpolationOrder = 0, because for my case I want it to be essentially a 3DArray plot.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour. `ListPlot3D` draws a surface connecting **points**. `InterpolationOrder -> 0` means it interpolates _between_ points with a flat, horizontal surface. You have $5\times 10$ points, so you have $4\times 9$ _intervals_ between the points, so you have also $4\times 9$ surfaces interpolating between the points. [This thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132209/3d-plot-of-x-y-z-that-looks-like-histogram3d) might give you ideas on how to proceed to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression it would plot each point and just give it a volume of sorts! I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: Related Q/As: [Height-dependent filling color in 3D Data Plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3333/125) and [How can I imitate the style of a certain 3D bar chart?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21460/125)

Answer (score 3):

For the requirement

> *I want it to be essentially a 3DArray plot.*

you can use `DiscretePlot3D` using your `Temp` to define a function `foo`:

```
ClearAll[foo];
(foo[##2] = #) & @@@ (Join @@ MapIndexed[Flatten@{##} &, Temp, {2}]);


DiscretePlot3D[foo[t, u], {t, 1, 10}, {u, 1, 5}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1/2, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]